# Nokia 7.1 recovery mode adb shell

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, data-recovery, linux, nokia-7.1

Recently, my Nokia 7.1 stopped booting properly. When I turn it on, it just goes to the "android one" scree, then stops. I managed to boot into recovery mode, and I got the following options:

```
Reboot system now
Reboot to bootloader
Apply update from ADB
Apply update from SD card
Wipe data/factory reset
Mount /system
View recovery logs
Run graphics test
Run locale test
Power off
```

When I try to connect to my phone with "adb shell", I get the following error message:

```
error: no devices/emulators found
```

Is there a way to connect to my phone from ADB, running on my Linux computer, so I can recover data from it?

Comment: Stock recovery built under "user" mode doesn't have ADB enabled. If your bootloader is still locked (which is likely given yours is a Nokia), I don't see a way out.

Comment: instead of desoldering emmc one could just dump emmc in edl mode. but it's pointless because of encryption https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition

Answer (score 1):

The stock recovery can only make use of ADB for sideloading of packages under the "Apply update from ADB" option in recovery. You cannot perform any other adb tasks.

Also, the issue that you are facing is mostly related to emmc which has gone into a r/o mode probably due to its lifecycle being all used up. As such, it is impossible to mount the emmc and recover any data. There may be some possibilities with desoldering of emmc and advanced read/write tools, but that's some advanced engineering thing.